# heterogeneous task & homogeneous task

Tags: java, multithreading, task

What's the definition of these two, and what's the difference between a "heterogeneous task" and a "homogeneous task"?  When I read the *Java Concurrency In Practice* book, these two phrases jumped out.  In my opinion within the book, it is the task size and handling time of task.  But I don't understand it that well.  I've googled it, but can't find the accurate answer.  Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Homogeneous tasks**: group of tasks that are processed in a similar way and take approximately the same amount of time. Example: applying the square function to each element of an array. Pattern: Data-parallelism.
- **Heterogeneous tasks**: group of tasks that have no clear logical relation and may execute in various amounts of time. Example: estimating pi in parallel with downloading a web page. Pattern: Task-parallelism.

Comment: Where can I find the definition of Data-parallelism and Task-parallelism , or can you give me a link to them , I think I don't know their meaning.

Comment: @ohyeahchenzai: Sure, you can find basic definitions on the wiki pages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_parallelism and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_parallelism

Answer (score 0):

It's probably referring to something like this:

- Heterogenous tasks are *fundamentally different tasks*. For example, "Fetch latest weather" vs "Fetch latest news". This is sometimes referred to as *task-based parallelism*.
- Homogenous tasks are tasks which perform the same task, but potentially with different input. For example, "I have 20 stock tickers - fetch the stock price for each ticker". This is sometimes referred to as *data-based parallelism*.

(Note that the meaning task/data-based parallelism seems to vary according to context. Hopefully the above is correct in at least some contexts ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think what they mean in the context of the book is that if you have 20 tasks, 19 that take 10ms to complete each and the other one 1s to complete. Running them sequentially or concurrently won't make a huge difference: it will take more or less 1s.

If you have 20 tasks that all take 10ms to complete and are independent, you can significantly reduce the execution time by running them concurrently vs. sequentially.

Comment: I think what you have expressed is the task size and the their relation(if independent), if the book has said so , I may be more clear , but these two phrases jumped out without explanation , and my English is not so well , so I asked this question to check if anyone has a more formal definition of these two!